# Laravel Passport using api (not using blade)

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I am creating a vue-application, using Larvel Passport as the backend. I would like to avoid having client-id on the server. That would mean creating my own authorization-controller that do not have access the session-variables.

I see only one alternative:
Use the session-middleware, and make an alternative to code here:
https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/9.x/src/Http/Controllers/AuthorizationController.php
Line: 61, 62 and 63

I struggle to see the solution.

I would be grateful if somebody could point me into the right direction, or somebody has some ideas they can share.

Comment: Another reason for moving away from session-variables is that the process is becoming stateless

Answer (score 0):

My solution became very simple. I copied AuthorizationController (mentioned above), removed all references to StatefulGuard, and placed the new controller inside of the route-group auth:api. In that way the user has to be logged in to authorize the client.